# Flask SQLAlchemy MySQL app with SQLite test db?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I've been working on a Flask app for a while, using SQLAlchemy to access a MySQL database. I've finally started looking into writing tests for this (I'm a strong believer in testing, but am new to Flask and SQLA and Python for that matter, so delayed this), and am having a problem getting my structure set up.

My production database isn't using any unusual MySQL features, and in other languages/frameworks I've been able to set up a test framework using an in-memory SQLite database. (For example, I have a Perl app using `DBIx::Class` to run a SQL Server db but with a test suite built on SQLite.) However, with SQLAlchemy I've needed to declare a few specific MySQL things in my model, and I'm not sure how to get around this. In particular, I use TINYINT and CHAR types for a few columns, and I seem to have to import these from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql, since these aren't generic types in SQLA. Thus I'll have a class declaration like:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    ...
    size = db.Column(TINYINT, db.ForeignKey('size.size_id'), nullable=False)
```

So even though if I were using raw SQL, I could use TINYINT with SQLite or MySQL and it would work fine, here, it's coming from the mysql dialect class.

I don't want to override my entire model class in order to cover seemingly trivial things like this. Is there some other solution? I've read what I could about using different databases for testing and production, but this issue hasn't been mentioned. It would be a lot easier to use an in-memory SQLite db for testing, instead of having to have a MySQL test database available for everything.

Comment: At a risk of sounding really nitpicky, you shouldn't need a DB for unit testing. It's a different story for integration tests and above, in which you probably should be using the target DB. But: your specific typing issue is maybe solvable using a variant: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator.with_variant. For more complex cases you might have to write your own `TypeDecorator`, like the [backend agnostic GUID type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type).

Comment: Your nitpick was entirely correct: I wrote "unit tests" but in fact I'm writing both unit and integration tests. I've edited my post to remove "unit" entirely.

Thank you for the suggestions, which look like they'll be able to solve this problem.